# How do you print raw UTF-8 characters from their numbers?

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8

Say I wanted to print a `ÿ` (latin small y with diaeresis) from its Unicode/UTF-8 number of `U+00FF` or hex of `c3 bf`. **How can I do that in PHP?**

*The reason* is that I need to be able to create certain UTF-8 Characters is for testing in my regex and string functions. However, since I have less than 200 keys on my keyboard *I can't type them* - and since many times I am stuck in an ASCII only world - I need to be able to create them bases solely off of their *ASCII safe*, UTF-8 character code.

*Note: In order for it show correctly in a browser I know that the first step is*

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: For the record, the related question with the accepted answer, actually also answers (better) this one.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748956/how-would-you-create-a-string-of-all-utf-8-characters-php

Comment: Do you mean, the unicode codepoint of U+00FF which is represented by the UTF-8 byte sequence of `c3 bf`? Sorry, but I was a bit confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

well you have everything you need.
Hex values being recognized in double-quoted strings as well

```
echo "\xc3\xbf";
```

Comment: There's half the problem solved. I was not aware of the "\x..." trick. But what about the `U+00FF` number - how can you represent that in PHP - *or can you?*

Comment: I wonder if you can compose the hex value from a decimal value like `print "\x". 191;`...

Comment: @Xeon base conversion is very simple task, can be accomplished by any beginner programmer manually. there is also some function in PHP I believe, as well as in any other language.
to recode U+00FF is also possible, and you have the function aready. Or this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140660/how-to-get-uxxxx-to-display-correctly-using-php5
Anyway to ask only a half of your problem isn't too good practice.

Comment: I didn't ask half - I asked for both parts. However, I'm not sure there is a valid answer for first type of unicode number conversion in which case your answer is 100% correct.

Comment: @Xeon, yeah, my bad, you asked both. sorry

Comment: How about just writing the codepoint as an html entity and use this: `html_entity_decode('&#x00ff;', ENT_IGNORE, 'utf-8');`?

Comment: Note that the UTF-8 sequence is very different from the unicode codepoint and it's worth knowning the difference.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 with a small pack function**

```
<?php

function chr_utf8($n,$f='C*'){
return $n<(1<<7)?chr($n):($n<1<<11?pack($f,192|$n>>6,1<<7|191&$n):
($n<(1<<16)?pack($f,224|$n>>12,1<<7|63&$n>>6,1<<7|63&$n):
($n<(1<<20|1<<16)?pack($f,240|$n>>18,1<<7|63&$n>>12,1<<7|63&$n>>6,1<<7|63&$n):'')));
}

echo chr_utf8(9405).chr_utf8(9402).chr_utf8(9409).chr_utf8(9409).chr_utf8(9412);

//Output ⒽⒺⓁⓁⓄ
```

Check it in https://eval.in/748062 …

**Solution 2 with json_decode**

```
<?php

$utf8_char='["';
for($number=0;$number<55296;$number++)
$utf8_char.='\u'.substr('000'.strtoupper(dechex($number)),-4).'","';
$utf8_char=json_decode(substr($utf8_char,0,-2).']');

echo $utf8_char[9405].$utf8_char[9402].$utf8_char[9409].$utf8_char[9409].$utf8_char[9412];

//Output ⒽⒺⓁⓁⓄ
```