# How would you create a string of all UTF-8 characters?

Tags: php, string, unicode, utf-8

There are many ways to represent the +1 million [UTF-8 characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). Take the latin capital "A" with macron (`Ā`). This is unicode code point `U+0100`, hex number `0xc4 0x80`, decimal number `196 128`, and binary `11000100 10000000`.

I would like to create a collection of the first 65,535 UTF-8 characters for use in testing applications. These are all unicode characters up to code point `U+FFFF` (byte3).

Is it possible to do something like a `for($x=0)` loop and then convert the resulting decimal to another base (like hex) which would allow the creation of the matching unicode character?

I can create the value `Ā` using something like this:

```
$char = "\xc4\x80";
// or
$char = chr(196).chr(128);
```

However, I am not sure how to turn this into an automated process.

```
// fail!
$char = "\x". dechex($a). "\x". dexhex($b);
```

Comment: `U+FFFF` is not a Unicode character by definition (neither is `U+FFFE`, it's used as a Byte Order Mark instead).

Comment: You question rather confuses codepoints (numbers) with encodings (bytes sequence). A more precise statement would be. "This is unicode code point U+0100 (in decimal: 256), and its UTF-8 encoding is two bytes: 0xc4 0x80 (or in decimal 196, 128) ..."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can leverage `iconv` (or a few other functions) to convert a code point number to a UTF-8 string:

```
function unichr($i)
{
    return iconv('UCS-4LE', 'UTF-8', pack('V', $i));
}

$codeunits = array();
for ($i = 0; $i<0xD800; $i++)
    $codeunits[] = unichr($i);
for ($i = 0xE000; $i<0xFFFF; $i++)
    $codeunits[] = unichr($i);
$all = implode($codeunits);
```

(I avoided the surrogate range 0xD800–0xDFFF as they aren't valid to put in UTF-8 themselves; that would be “CESU-8”.)

Comment: +1 Bingo. This is the best way, I guess. You take eachcodepoint (integer), pack it in 32 bits LE (which amounts to "encode" it yourself by hand in UCS-4LE), and ask iconv to convert the encoding to UTF-8. (Did I already say that PHP sucks at Unicode?)

Comment: I'm not sure. I can say “PHP sucks at Unicode” for you just in case you didn't, if that'd help.

Comment: Awesome! I now have a useful list of UTF-8 characters to run through regex tests.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you can do this programmatically, mostly because there is a difference between a Unicode code point and a character. See http://www.unicode.org/standard/where for a few examples of characters that are represented by a combination of code points.

Some code points make no sense on their own and can only be used in conjunction with another character (think accents). See http://www.unicode.org/charts/charindex.html for a list of code points, and look at the section with all the "combining" code points.

Also, for use in testing applications, you'd need something else besides a list of possible UTF-8 code points, namely several invalid/malformed UTF-8 sequences that your app needs to be able to recover gracefully from.

For this, take a look at [Markus Kuhn's Unicode stress test](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/UTF-8-test.txt).

Answer (score 1):

I quickly translated this from C, but it should give you the idea:

```
function encodeUTF8( $inValue ) {
    $result = "";

    if ( $inValue < 0x00000080 ) {
        $result .= chr( $inValue );
        $extra = 0;
    } else if ( $inValue < 0x00000800 ) {
        $result .= chr( 0x00C0 | ( ( $inValue >> 6 ) & 0x001F ) );
        $extra = 6;
    } else if ( $inValue < 0x00010000 ) {
        $result .= chr( 0x00E0 | ( ( $inValue >> 12 ) & 0x000F ) );
        $extra = 12;
    } else if ( $inValue < 0x00200000 ) {
        $result .= chr( 0x00F0 | ( ( $inValue >> 18 ) & 0x0007 ) );
        $extra = 18;
    } else if ( $inValue < 0x04000000 ) {
        $result .= chr( 0x00F8 | ( ( $inValue >> 24 ) & 0x0003 ) );
        $extra = 24;
    } else if ( $inValue < 0x80000000 ) {
        $result .= chr( 0x00FC | ( ( $inValue >> 30 ) & 0x0001 ) );
        $extra = 30;
    }

    while ( $extra > 0 ) {
        $result .= chr( 0x0080 | ( ( $inValue >> ( $extra -= 6 ) ) & 0x003F ) );
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The logic is sound but I am not sure about the php so be sure to check it over.  I have never tried to use `chr` like this.

There are a lot of values that you would not want to encode, like 0xD000-0xDFFF, 0xE000-0xF8FF and 0xFFF0-0xFFFF, and there are several other gaps for combining characters and reserved characters.

Answer (score 0):

:)
of course last one wouldn't work. \x sequence belongs to the double-quoted strings.

what's wrong with `$char = chr(196).chr(128);` ? with chr($a).chr($b) I mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function chr_utf8($n,$f='C*'){
return $n<(1<<7)?chr($n):($n<1<<11?pack($f,192|$n>>6,1<<7|191&$n):
($n<(1<<16)?pack($f,224|$n>>12,1<<7|63&$n>>6,1<<7|63&$n):
($n<(1<<20|1<<16)?pack($f,240|$n>>18,1<<7|63&$n>>12,1<<7|63&$n>>6,1<<7|63&$n):'')));
}

echo implode('',array_map('chr_utf8',range(0,65535)));

// Output a big string, you can increase the range to 1114111…
```

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a `mb_chr()` function in PHP that returns the character for a UTF-8 code point.