# unicode characters (like emoticons) in telegram bot message (or keyboard)

Tags: php, unicode, telegram-bot

I'm playing with Telegram bot development.
The only thing in which i have no success is sending unicode characters.

The way i call the "sendMessage" api is in php with curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array("chat_id" => $chat_id, "text" => "\u2b50"));
```

The code above should post a star icon on the chat, but instead shows the exact text:

> \u2b50

- Escaping the text ("\\u2b50") doesn't work.
- If the bot acts as an echo (replies with the received text) when typing "\u2b50" in the client, it replies with the star icon.
- same behavior has for the keyboard keys (reply_markup.keyboard)

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
solved with solution from bobince (thanks!).

used inline function like:

```
$text = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) {
    return iconv('UCS-4LE', 'UTF-8', pack('V', hexdec($match[1])));
}, $text);
```

or

```
$text = preg_replace("/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/e", "iconv('UCS-4LE','UTF-8',pack('V', hexdec('U$1')))", $text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "\u2b50"

[PHP string literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) syntax doesn't have `\u` escapes, primarily because PHP strings are not Unicode-based, they're just a list of bytes.

Consequently if you want to include a non-ASCII character in a string you need to encode the character to bytes using whatever encoding the consumer of your output will be expecting.

If the Telegram web service is expecting to receive UTF-8 (and I've no idea if it is, but it's a good guess for any modern web app), then the UTF-8-encoded bytes for U+2B50 are 0xE2, 0xAD and 0x90, and so the string literal you should use is:

```
"\xE2\xAD\x90"
```

If you want to convert a Unicode codepoint to a UTF-8 string more generally:

```
function unichr($i) {
    return iconv('UCS-4LE', 'UTF-8', pack('V', $i));
}

unichr(0x2B50)   // "\xE2\xAD\x90"
```

Comment: now, how convert unicode characters like "\ud83d\udc4e" (emoticon for thumb down).

i found this thread (with your response) and tried all combinations, without success:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748956/how-would-you-create-a-string-of-all-utf-8-characters

Comment: 0xd83d, 0xdc4e are UTF-16 surrogate code units representing U+1F44E Thumbs Down, so `unichr(0x1F44E)`, which gives UTF-8 byte string `"\xF0\x9F\x91\x8E"`.

Comment: i'm impressed, but i did'n understand how to convert (0xd83d, 0xdc4e) into 0x1F44E...
this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24763655/5091220 have functions i can use. thank you

Comment: Accepted answer is correct but make sure you put the code between double quotes, not single quotes! (I don't have enough reputation to comment and I thought this is important" `
$rocket .= "\xF0\x9F\x9A\x80"; //works
$rocket .= '\xF0\x9F\x9A\x80'; // does not work`

Answer (score 0):

set the charset to unicode...

```
$headers = array(
           "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset: UTF-8"
        );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $headers );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, array("chat_id" => $chat_id, "text" => "\u2b50"));
```

Comment: no way to use "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ==> "400 (Bad Request)" from server.
the only accepted content-type is "multipart/form-data", but no luck with "Content-Type: multipart/form-data; charset: UTF-8", already tried
=(