# List of UTF8 non-ASC occurrences not working

Tags: php, utf-8, char

The PHP library lacks a `mb_ord()` function... That is, something that do what [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) function do, but for UTF8 (or "mb" multibyte, so "mb_ord"). I used some clues from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333098),

```
 $ord = hexdec( bin2hex($utf8char) ); //decimal
```

and I suppose that `mb_substr($text, $i, 1,  'UTF-8')` gets "1 utf8-char"... But $ord not returns the values that we expect.

### CONTEXT

This code not works: not shows code like 177  (plusmn).

```
 $msg = '';
 $text = "... a UTF-8 long text... Ą ⨌ 2.5±0.1; 0.5±0.2 ...";
 $allOrds = array(); 
 for($i=0; $i<mb_strlen($text, 'UTF-8'); $i++) {
    $utf8char = mb_substr($text, $i, 1,  'UTF-8'); // 1=1 unicode character?
    $ord = hexdec( bin2hex($utf8char) ); //decimal 
    if ($ord>126) { //non-ASCII
      if (isset($allOrds[$ord])) $allOrds[$ord]++; else $allOrds[$ord]=1;
    }
 }
 foreach($allOrds as $o=>$n)
    $msg.="\n entity #$o occurs $n times";
 echo $msg;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
entity #50308 occurs 1 times
entity #14854284 occurs 1 times
entity #49841 occurs 2 times
```

So (see [entities table](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref)), 49841 is not 177, and 14854284 (iiiint) is not 10764.

Comment: Could you start with an introductory sentence on what you're trying to do here?

Comment: If you want further answers to an existing question, then I'm afraid this one should be closed as duplicate. Can you please clarify what your question is?

Comment: Thanks, I edited, adding an introduction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> something that do what ord() function do, but for UTF8

For that you'd first need to define what exactly that is. `ord` gives you the *numerical value of a byte*. This is often confused as "value of the character", but since encodings are a complex topic that makes no sense. So, `ord` == numerical value of a byte. What would you expect the "MB version of `ord`" to do then exactly?

Anyway, what you're getting is the numeric value of two (or more) bytes. Say, the character "漢" in UTF-8 is encoded as the three bytes `E6 BC A2`. That's what `bin2hex` gives you. `hexdec` then translates that to decimal, which is a pretty large number. That number has absolutely nothing to do with the *Unicode code point* 6F22, which you're really after. That is because the UTF-8 encoding needs a few more extra bytes to encode this code point, hence U+6F22 (漢) does not translate into the bytes `6F 22`.

You have already linked to another question which does what you want:

```
list(, $ord) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($utf8Character, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
```

This essentially uses the same logic, but bases it on the UCS-4 encoding, in which code points happen to correspond to bytes quite nicely.

Comment: The `mb_ord($c)` returns a "numerical value of a multibyte (utf symbol)", and I think it is a lack of PHP.

Comment: What does "numerical value of multibyte" mean? Do you want a hypothetical `mb_ord` to return you the *Unicode code point*? What about `mb_ord($str)` where `$str` is Shift-JIS encoded  (or some other non-Unicode encoding)?

Comment: thanks your solution works fine!  I used [the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333307/287948) at first implementation, but not worked at my loop... was my bug.

Comment: About semantic discussion: perhaps the better definition and more precise and formal term for "numerical value of a multibyte symbol" is at W3C "numerical entity" definition... The entity was encoded into the UTF8 character, so the translation is from "character encoded entity" (see [table](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for utf8 decimal codes example) to its decimal value... It is obvious and intuitive from this point of view.

Comment: And that numeric value is based on the Unicode table. While I certainly agree it would be helpful to have a simple built-in function to get the Unicode codepoint of any particular character, this is just as arbitrary a classification as anything else.