# PHP get ASCII code of a character

Tags: php, ascii, urlencode

How can I get the ASCII code of a character in PHP ??

http://www.backbone.se/urlencodingUTF8.htm

When I try:

```
$h = dechex(ord('ñ'));

echo $h;
```

I'm getting `C3` when I should be getting `f1`

I want for example:

```
for 'ñ' -> %f1
for 'º' -> %ba
```

How can I get that?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "ord — Return ASCII value of character" - the PHP Documentation. Keyword here being "ASCII". `'ñ'` is not ASCII (_maybe_ UTF-8 ?).

Comment: `ord` returns ASCII value of character. ASCII doesn't contain the `ñ`.

Comment: *It's not ascii* ? So what is this http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/enie-spanish-enye-lowercase-letter-n-tilde-ascii-code-164.html ? It is from *extended* ascii but it is ascii

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333098/utf-8-safe-equivelant-of-ord-or-charcodeat-in-php

Answer (score 3):

As they told you in the comments, ñ is not *standard* ASCII. It is present on the extended ASCII table, *but* your source file may be saved in UTF-8 and thus ñ is stored with different bytes. You could try setting your editor to save documents in a different charset.

*However*, what you're doing is really dangerous. Since as you see encoding can change, it's always a bad idea to write in source files characters that are not part of standard ASCII.

Why do you need to do that operation? Is there another way? Can't you use UTF-8?