# Parse UTF-8 string char-by-char in PHP

Tags: php, string, encoding, utf-8

I'm sorry if I'm asking the obvious, but I can't seem to find a working solution for a simple task. On the input I have a string, provided by a user, encoded with UTF-8 encoding. I need to sanitize it by removing all characters less than `0x20` (or space), except `0x7` (or tab.)

The following works for ANSI strings, but not for UTF-8:

```
$newName = "";
$ln = strlen($name);
for($i = 0; $i < $ln; $i++)
{
    $ch = substr($name, $i, 1);
    $och = ord($ch);
    if($och >= 0x20 ||
        $och == 0x9)
    {
        $newName .= $ch;
    }
}
```

It totally missed UTF-8 encoded characters and treats them as bytes. I keep finding posts where people suggest using `mb_` functions, but that still doesn't help me. (For instance, I tried calling `mb_strlen($name, "utf-8");` instead of `strlen`, but it still returns the length of string in `BYTEs` instead of characters.)

Any idea how to do this in PHP?

PS. Sorry, my PHP is somewhat rusty.

Answer (score 1):

If you use multibyte functions (`mb_`) then you have to use them for everything. In this example you should use `mb_strlen()` and `mb_substr()`.

The reason it is not working is probably because you are using `ord()`. It only works with ASCII values:

```
ord
(PHP 4, PHP 5)
ord — Return ASCII value of character
...
Returns the ASCII value of the first character of string.
```

In other words, if you throw a multibyte character into `ord()` it will only use the first byte, and throw away the rest.

Comment: OK, just to start off, why does `mb_strlen` still return the size in bytes instead of characters?

Comment: @ahmd0 It shouldn't. Could you provide an example string?

Comment: OK. My bad. I was passing it the string that I got from calling `mb_convert_encoding`.

Comment: Still, what about `ord`. It doesn't have `mb_ord` equivalent. Does it?

Comment: `ord()` returns the ordinal number of *a byte*. Multibyte strings have more than one byte (hence the name), so nope, it is not possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, what? You're saying in PHP it's not possible to convert a `char` into its Unicode ordinal value. Did I get it right?

Comment: Well, you cannot using `ord()`. [This question may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333098/utf-8-safe-equivelant-of-ord-or-charcodeat-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Wow, PHP is one messed up language. Here's what worked for me (but how much slower will this run for a longer chunk of text...):

```
function normalizeName($name, $encoding_2_use, $encoding_used)
{
    //'$name' = string to normalize
    //          INFO: Must be encoded with '$encoding_used' encoding
    //'$encoding_2_use' = encoding to use for return string (example: "utf-8")
    //'$encoding_used' = encoding used to encode '$name' (can be also "utf-8")
    //RETURN:
    //      = Name normalized, or
    //      = "" if error
    $resName = "";

    $ln = mb_strlen($name, $encoding_used);
    if($ln !== false)
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < $ln; $i++)
        {
            $ch = mb_substr($name, $i, 1, $encoding_used);

            $arp = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($ch, 'UCS-4BE', $encoding_used));
            if(count($arp) >= 1)
            {
                $och = intval($arp[1]);    //Index 1?! I don't understand why, but it works...
                if($och >= 0x20 || $och == 0x9)
                {
                    $ch2 = mb_convert_encoding('&#'.$och.';', $encoding_2_use, 'HTML-ENTITIES');
                    $resName .= $ch2;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $resName;
}
```