# Two different special characters are equal

Tags: php, apache, special-characters

I'm trying to compare 2 different special characters, but they are equal when I compare them.

```
$char1= "";
$char2= "";

echo mb_detect_encoding($char1, 'UTF-8', true); // 'UTF-8'
echo mb_detect_encoding($char2, 'UTF-8', true); // 'UTF-8'

if($char1 == $char2) // TRUE
echo strcmp($char1, $char2); // 0
```

Apache/2.4.10

PHP/5.6.3

PhpStorm 9.0.2

What can I do to make a valid comparison?

Thank you.

Comment: what are those special characters?

Comment: @Anant, copy paste them localy, e.g. Windows start menu (search box), it can read them.

Comment: `var_dump($char1 == $char2)` gives me `FALSE` with your two characters. Can you confirm your result?  maybe you could try `strcmp` to do your comparison.  It returns `0` if the strings are equal.

Comment: @BeetleJuice, how? it gives TRUE to me. My PHP script is saved as UTF-8. I also tried binary compare, same result.

Comment: I don't know how. It's strange.  I've confirmed my results here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5a3300372aa4cf6c687dfcc15d4004ba07a40d6d

Comment: @BeetleJuice, Do you maybe know if there is some setting on my server to correct this?

Comment: sorry I don't, but if you find out what's going on, please write up an answer so it will help the next person.

Comment: Yes, of course! Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Check out whether my answer works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can I do to make a valid comparison?

**Updated Solution**

Perhaps we're looking at this the wrong way. The problem may have nothing to do with PHP, but be about your code editor instead. Perhaps the editor is registering both chars as the same when you enter them, so PHP doesn't see any difference.  Here is what you can do:

1. Save each char in a file by itself, using an editor that recognizes the character, such as `Wordpad`
2. Load the character in PHP with `$char=file_get_contents('path/to/char.txt')`
3. Now that we've bypassed your code editor entirely, compare the two. If they're different, your editor might be to blame.

**Original Solution**

You could try to convert your characters to their ASCII values and compare the values instead of the characters

```
$ordUTF8 = function($char){
    list(, $ord) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
    return $ord;
};
$char1= "";
$char2= "";
// 61656 and 61558 in my testing
$isEqual = $ordUTF8($char1)===$ordUTF8($char2);
```

[Live demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5a0165b6893efb24174d65e9a332dd66d5654e4a). This solution was inspired by [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333098/utf-8-safe-equivelant-of-ord-or-charcodeat-in-php)

Comment: Returns true... :(

Comment: Perhaps we're looking at it from the wrong angle. Maybe it has to do with your code editor? What if you save each character as its own text file, using an editor like Wordpad. Then in PHP, use `$char = file_get_contents('path/to/file.txt')` to retrieve the character?

Comment: I think its some apache configuration problem... I tried setting default charset, tried to read from another file, still incorrect :/

Comment: You were right, I put each char as separate file, and it works now, lol