# Why result from ord PHP not same as result from charCodeAt javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Why result from ord PHP not same as result from charCodeAt javascript ?

Result from PHP is `230 143 144`

And result from javascript is `25552`

How to apply php code to get result as same as javascript result ?

.

.

javascript

```
<script>
var someString = "提";

for(var i=0;i<someString.length;i++) {
    var char = someString.charCodeAt(i);
    alert(char);
}
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$s = '提';

for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen( $s ); $i++ ) {
    print ord( $s[ $i ] ) . "\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: duplicated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333098/utf-8-safe-equivelant-of-ord-or-charcodeat-in-php

Comment: Why not work ?  `<?php
$s = '提';
for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen( $s ); $i++ ) { 
 list(, $ord) = unpack('N', mb_convert_encoding($s[ $i ], 'UCS-4BE', 'UTF-8'));
    print $ord;     
}
?>`

Answer (score 0):

Because there are like a hundred different ways to encode text in a computer. Additionally:

- PHP does not really know that encoding your data is using
- JavaScript did not really implement Unicode correctly until recent versions (though this is not relevant in this particular case)

Your character (提) is listed in the Unicode catalogue as ['hold in hand; lift in hand' (U+63D0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/63d0/index.htm) and has, among many others, the following encodings:

- AS UTF-8: `0xE6 0x8F 0x90`
- AS UTF-16: `0x63D0` (`25552` in decimal)

Your PHP file appears to be saved as UTF-8 (that's something you can check in your text editor) thus 提 is encoded in three bytes but your code splits the single character the individual bytes.

Your JavaScript function, however, prints the UTF-16 encoding as [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt).

PHP provides a couple of builtin functions to convert between encodings:

```
$as_utf8 = '提';
var_dump( unpack('n', mb_convert_encoding($as_utf8, 'UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8')) );
var_dump( unpack('n', iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE', $as_utf8)) );
```