# Convert string to it's correspondent entity

Tags: php, regex, string, encode

So I have this annonymous function that converts every character of my string into entity.

```
var myStr = myStr.replace(/[\u0022\u0027\u0080-\FFFF]/g, function(a) {
   return '&#' + a.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
});
```

I need to do the same with PHP.
I'll have a normal string and *transform it it's equivalent entity code*.
e.g:

Have --> Want: `Képzeld el PDF` ------->`K&#233;pzeld el PDF`

I was reading about [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

> Perform a regular expression search and replace using a callback

But I don't know how to apply the same thing in PHP.
I could also use the annonymous function within preg_replace, like so:

```
 $line = preg_replace_callback(
        '/[\u0022\u0027\u0080-\FFFF]/g',
        function ($matches) {
            return '&#' + a.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
        },
    );
```

I couldn't make it work or find an equivalence for `charCodeAt`.
Even the regex range of characters are not supported by `preg_replace` function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333098/utf-8-safe-equivelant-of-ord-or-charcodeat-in-php

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha

Comment: There's also [`mb_ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ord.php) and [`mb_chr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-chr.php) and their associated [polyfill](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/polyfill-mbstring) for PHP<7.2.

Comment: `return '&#' . a.charCodeAt($matches[0]) + ';';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like "\u00ed" to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-cha)

Comment: php does NOT have `charCodeAt`. Also, the question is not about this function equivalent only.

Comment: @Sammitch Thanks for the suggestion topic, but it does not apply here. The output is the characters itself I need the entity code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`IntlChar::ord()`](http://php.net/manual/en/intlchar.ord.php) to find the codepoint of a character. Below is a transpiled version:

```
$myStr = preg_replace_callback('~[\x{0022}\x{0027}\x{0080}-\x{ffff}]~u', function ($c) {
    return '&#' . IntlChar::ord($c[0]) . ';';
}, $myStr);
```

See [live demo](https://3v4l.org/7UFMq)

Comment: Sounds beautiful. But It's saying that "Class `IntlChar` not found".

Comment: See requirements http://php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php and read [installation](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php).

Comment: Instead you could use [this version](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php#109812) of `ord`.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro My pleasure.

Comment: Would this be too complicated to extend the range of characters to all of them ? even the normal ones like "a, b, e, d ,f "

Comment: It would be much easier. Using `preg_replace_callback` regex should be `~.~u`