# what would the equivalent php version be of the following nodejs md5 hashing source code?

Tags: php, node.js, md5, cryptojs, digest

I'm migrating from nodejs to PHP and I couldn't obtain a similar output md5 hash digest for the below snippet having the same input.Perhaps there's something I'm missing.

```
var md5sum = crypto.createHash('md5');
md5sum.update(new Buffer(str, 'binary'));
md5_result = md5sum.digest('hex');
```

Thanks in advance for your help!!!, Btw, my nodejs version is 10.1.0, and npm version is 5.6.0. And for the ones asking, this source code equivalent is not `md5($str)` and it is not my code, I'm just converting it. For example, for the following input `42b86318d761e13ef90c126c3e060582¤3¤724039¤1` the obtained digest is `9860bd2248c069c7b65045917c215596`.

I just tried to run the following snippet at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_nodejs_online.php, taking into account your proposals but they don't work:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
var str = "42b86318d761e13ef90c126c3e060582¤3¤724039¤1";
var md5sum = crypto.createHash('md5');
md5sum.update(new Buffer(str, 'binary'));
const md5_result = md5sum.digest('hex');
const md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(str).digest('hex');
const expected_digest = "9860bd2248c069c7b65045917c215596";
console.log("original version digest:" + md5_result);
console.log("proposed equivalent digest:" + md5);
console.log("expected digest:" + expected_digest);
```

What I get on that site is:
`original version digest:9860bd2248c069c7b65045917c215596
proposed equivalent digest:b8ee918f782fe7135b25c1fa59339094
expected digest:9860bd2248c069c7b65045917c215596`

Other sites such as https://www.katacoda.com/courses/nodejs/playground,https://repl.it/ ,https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-nodejs-online support my claim (i.e. md5 digest is `9860bd2248c069c7b65045917c215596`), however,so far, this site http://rextester.com/l/nodejs_online_compiler outputs what some of you obtained(i.e. `b8ee918f782fe7135b25c1fa59339094`). As I said before, please, help me find a PHP EQUIVALENT version of the first nodejs snippet of code.

Comment: @RolandStarke it's not the same, it was the first thing I tried, obviously

Comment: `9860bd2248c069c7b65045917c215596` is not correct, it should be: `b8ee918f782fe7135b25c1fa59339094`, look at my answer, which is correct.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande please,just run the second snippet and see it yourself

Comment: I see it, and your snippet is wrong as I stated. your expected digest is **wrong**, the correct `md5` for that string, is `b8ee918f782fe7135b25c1fa59339094`, my answer is correct.

Comment: I don't know if you're doing it on purpose or not, what is it to hard to understand that: `9860bd2248c069c7b65045917c215596` is **not correct**, "other sites such as" **does not support your claim** you're just using the same code, that it isn't **correct**.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande as I stated above, it is not my code,and the only thing I want is to be able to replicate such output using PHP, I'm not interested in the correctness of such snippet of code.Let me reformulate the question:Is there a PHP code equivalent to the first node js snippet, which outputs the expect string "9860bd2248c069c7b65045917c215596"?

Comment: I Updated my answer with the php equivalent.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande thanks for the proposed solution, it is solved now, the issue here was due to the ¤ symbol.

Comment: Yeah, because you're converting it to 'binary'. But you should know for other projects, that you should just send the string as is, to `.update` if you want the correct & universal md5 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use: `new Buffer(str, 'binary')` just:

```
const md5 = crypto
    .createHash('md5')
    .update(string)
    .digest('hex');
```

Using that, you will get the same output with php `md5`, linux `md5sum`, and node.

For your input: `42b86318d761e13ef90c126c3e060582¤3¤724039¤1` the following commands will print the same:

**md5sum**

```
echo -n "42b86318d761e13ef90c126c3e060582¤3¤724039¤1" | md5sum
```

**PHP**

```
echo md5("42b86318d761e13ef90c126c3e060582¤3¤724039¤1");
```

**Node**

```
require('crypto')
        .createHash('md5')
        .update("42b86318d761e13ef90c126c3e060582¤3¤724039¤1")
        .digest('hex');
```

All three will output: `b8ee918f782fe7135b25c1fa59339094`

**NOTE:**

`new Buffer` is deprecated, `Buffer.from` should be used instead.

> Other sites such as
>   https://www.katacoda.com/courses/nodejs/playground,https://repl.it/
>   ,https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-nodejs-online support my claim (i.e.
>   md5 digest is 9860bd2248c069c7b65045917c215596)

**They're not supporting your claim**, you're executing the same code, which is wrong, on many different node.js environment. Of course every Node.js environment will print that output for your code, that doesn't make it right.

---

Since you can't modify the code, and you want the PHP equivalent, here it is:

```
function utf8_char_code_at($str, $index) {
    $char = mb_substr($str, $index, 1, 'UTF-8');

    if (mb_check_encoding($char, 'UTF-8')) {
        $ret = mb_convert_encoding($char, 'UTF-32BE', 'UTF-8');
        return hexdec(bin2hex($ret));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

function myMD5($str) {

     $tmp = "";

     for($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($str); $i++)
        $tmp .= bin2hex(chr(utf8_char_code_at($str, $i)));

     return md5(hex2bin($tmp));
}

echo myMD5($string);
```

`utf8_char_code_at` taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18499265/1119863

It will output: `9860bd2248c069c7b65045917c215596` same as your node snippet.