# What is the correct syntax in php to echo UTF-8?

Tags: php, html, utf-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you print raw UTF-8 characters from their numbers? [PHP]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748459/how-do-you-print-raw-utf-8-characters-from-their-numbers-php)

This code works : `echo ' & # 3 4 ; '` will print a double quote on my webpage.

This, on the other hand, is obviously wrong : `echo ' U + 2 5 B 2 '` just prints the literal characters.

What is the correct syntax?  By the way, that `U+25B2` should be an upward pointing triangle.  I would like to use it to over an html select with its down triangle.

Comment: php's echo doesn't care of what you output. So it outputs the exact bytes you've passed

Comment: As zerkms said, PHP is actually outputting EXACTLY what you tell it to.  What's going on behind the scenes is that your browser knows that the &#34; should be translated to a quote.  You'll have to use something similar to access the unicode values if you need them.

Comment: Do you want to output the actual character or just HTML special character entity?

Comment: The answer mentioned by mgibsonbr, is a good one.  From the jumping off points in there, I learned good info; was surprised how much of that was referrenced below by folk who replied.  Now I've got a solid black Uppointing triangle to cover the downpointing one of the html select device.  And learned about the UTF-8 to hex, prior to echoing.  Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same as you did with your quote:

```
echo '&#9650;';
```

You can find the HTML entity info on [FileFormat.Info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b2/index.htm).

Comment: Precisely.  No more, no less.  Exactimento. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Add below header in your PHP page. I think it should take care printing the desired character.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and echo your value using your UTF char as :

```
echo "\xE2\x96\xB2";
```

**Please Note**: `E2 96 B2` UTF-8 equivalent of `U+25B2` UTF-16 value for your upward pointing triangle.

Comment: This is completely incorrect. PHP is not Unicode-aware - `\x25B2` ends up printing as `%B2` (`%` being `\x25`).

Comment: @duskwuff: I used the wrong HexCode. Corrected in the answer. Hope its fine now.

Comment: While you're now technically correct, you're still not giving a particularly useful answer -- in particular, you haven't explained where E2 96 B2 comes from.

Comment: @duskwuff: Added the note in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`u+25b2` is simply a nicely formated human string, presenting the two bytes of a particular unicode character sequence.. By and of itself, the string form means nothing to a browser, because that's the human version. To see the actual character represented by that code sequence, you have to output the raw bytes, e.g. 0x25 and 0xb2.