# Hex to Unicode in PHP ( \u014D to ō)

Tags: php, unicode, hex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to decode Unicode escape sequences like “\u00ed” to proper UTF-8 encoded characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934563/how-to-decode-unicode-escape-sequences-like-u00ed-to-proper-utf-8-encoded-char)

How can I convert \u014D to ō in PHP?

Thank You

Comment: This post is in Python but maybe help :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/867866/convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf8-hex-in-python

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140660

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not immediate clear what you mean when you say *"to ō"*.  If you're asking how to convert it into a different encoding then a general approach is to use the [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function.  014D is the [UCS-2](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf) (unicode) for your desired function so, if you have a string containing the bytes 014D you could use

```
iconv('UCS-2', 'UTF-8', $s)
```

to convert from UCS-2 to UTF-8.  Similarly if you want to convert to a different encoding - although you need to be aware that not all encodings will include the character you are using.  You'll see from the iconv documentation that the //TRANSLIT option may help in that case.

Note that iconv is taking a byte sequence so, if you actually have a string containing a slash, then a u, then a 0 etc... you'll need to convert that into the byte sequence first.

Comment: @borrible - Does not seems correct, you want to re-test ?

Comment: @ajreal - make sure you're testing on a UCS-2 byte sequence.

Comment: @borrible - i try the code you posted, does not seems to work if the `$s = '\u014D';`, it converted to invalid Chinese characters

Comment: @ajreal - The code you give is not putting a UCS-2 byte sequence into $s, it's putting a \ followed by a u followed by a 0 etc...  You can see this if you `echo bin2hex($s)`.  As mentioned in my answer the iconv is designed for a string containing the byte 01 followed by 4D.

Comment: @borrible - Mind to update your answer to ensure the $s into UCS-2 byte sequence?

Comment: @borrible, @ajreal: UCS-2 is not somehow equivalent to Unicode as you allege. UCS-2 can no more hold all of Unicode than can ASCII hold all of Greek or Latin. Anyway, who still uses UCS-2? Talk about putting the backwards in backwards-compatible! UCS-2 is such an antemillennial legacy that it’s embarrassing to see people talk about.  Unicode is a logical set of numbers, whereas UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 are physical transforms that preserve all code points — unlike the *ipso facto* broken UCS-2!

Answer (score 1):

If you have the escape characters in the string you could use a messy exec statement.

```
$string = '\\u014D';
exec("\$string = '$string'");
```

This way, the Unicode escape sequence should be recognized and interpreted as a unicode character When the string is parsed.

Of course, you should never use exec unless **absolutely** necessary.